# Listing the parameters in a node using RESTassured library with Java

Tags: java, rest-assured

The webservice: http://services.groupkt.com/country/search?text=lands has 16 records returned from a GET request. In the records, there is a parameter called 'name'. So, there are 16 names and each name has a unique value (country). My intention is to list all the 16 values of the 'name'parameter using java and the RESTassured library. I tried this:

```
Response response = RestAssured.get("http://services.groupkt.com/country/search?text=lands").andReturn();
String json = response.getBody().asString();
JsonPath jp = new JsonPath(json);

List<String> ls = from(response).getList("RestResponse.result.name");// The 'from' text displays an error
```

An error was seen on the 'from' text and it says: The method from(String) in the type RestTest is not applicable for the arguments (Response). I am not sure how to rectify this. Is there a simple way to create a list of all the values of the 'name' parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `from(response)` to `from(jp)`. That should take care of the error you are getting.

The Response class (which is what the `get()` method returns) also supports [jsonPath](http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.5/io/restassured/response/ResponseBodyExtractionOptions.html#jsonPath--), so you could also refactor it to something like this:

```
List names= get("http://services.groupkt.com/country/search?text=lands").jsonPath().getList("RestResponse.result.name");
```

Comment: I changed from(response) to from(jp) but the error still persists. The second option you provided worked but my intention is to parse the json path separately from the get method, instead.

Comment: That sounds like a different question. How about this - if you think my answer have answered your original question to "_a simple way to create a list of all the values of the 'name' parameter_", please do me a favor and accept my answer? Then post a new question and we'll work on your next problem :)

Comment: Ok that's fine. Thank you